# Custom table view cell not animating when going into edit mode iOS 6+

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I have some custom table view cell which all use auto layout for positioning the subviews, but when I call `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]`, the table view cells are not animated into edit mode.

The only customization I did on the cells is adding two labels that are stretched over the content view of the cell.

I have verified that the `setEditing:animated` method of a table view cell receives `animated == YES`.

Is there a way to force these custom cells into animating in the minus on the left instead of it just appearing?

Comment: Are you sure you added your subviews to `cell.contentView` and not to `cell`?  Have you inspected the frame of `contentView` before and after the change?

Comment: What do you mean by " cells are not animated into edit mode"? Does the minus button on the left just appear, or are you talking about your labels not animating?

Comment: The cells were made in the interface builder so all labels are added to the contentView. The minus just appears and the labels just go to the right without animation.